# How do I change read-only variables in MySQL running on WAMP

Tags: mysql, sql, wamp

I need to change the "ft_min_word_len" server variable in MySQL.

I have tried adding it to the "my.ini" folder my MySQL folder and restarted MySQL, however it did not seem to update the server variable.

I am running MySQL 5.6.17 on WAMP 2.5.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are running WAMPServer 2.5 64bit there was a mistake in the `my.ini` file that may explain why it is not picking up your change!

Edit my.ini ( using the wampmanager menu system ), look for this in that file

```
[wampmysqld]
```

And change it to

```
[wampmysqld64]
```

This section header should match the service name used by MySQL which in the 64 bit version of Wampserver2.5 is `wampmysqld64`